# Vertical scroll bar redrawing in a datagridview with multiline cells

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I've been searching for a while on an answer to this problem. I have a datagridview in my vb.net app and the right most column holds multiline cells. The vertical scroll bar doesn't redraw correctly:

[image: Vertical scroll]

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: When does this happen - after you load data, after the user uses the VSB, etc.?

Comment: Hey, yeah. Once the data is loaded into the dgv the scrollbar becomes unusable. I have another identical dgv on the same form which doesn't use multiline cells and that works fine which leads me to believe that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx) on the DataGridView after you load it with data:

```
dataGridViewThatsGivingYouGrief.Refresh();
```